# Change recurrent start up time of an activity

Tags: java, android, startup

I used these classes to start my activity every day at 20:00.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

And this is the receiver class:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{ 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyApp.class);
       context.startService(service1);

     }
}
```

Now i want to let the user change the start up time in the MyApp.class (i must still do this class), but now i don't know how to replace the old start up time with the new one. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager`'s `cancel(PendingIntent intent)` method to remove the old startup time association:

```
boolean alarmExists = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, pendingIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

// remove any pre-existing alarms associated with this Intent
if (alarmExists) {
   alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
}
```

You can then re-create a repeating Alarm using the same logic.